# Why does TensorContract differ from reshaped arrays in Mathematica?

Tags: arrays, wolfram-mathematica, precision, tensor

I am recently trying to perform tensor calculations with Mathematica as I came across problems like these:

Given two tensors M,N (here matrices), I want to compute something like

```
m = RandomReal[{}, {2, 4}];
n = RandomReal[{}, {2, 4}];
TensorContract[TensorProduct[m, n], {2, 4}]
={{1.2092, 0.892127}, {0.497884, 0.14624}}
```

i.e. the contraction w.r.t. the second index respectively. But whenever I try to alternatively compute

```
m . Transpose[n, {2, 1}]
={{1.2092, 0.892127}, {0.497884, 0.14624}}
```

it looks like the same value but still the difference is non-vanishing:

```
TensorContract[TensorProduct[m, n], {2, 4}] - m . Transpose[n, {2, 1}]
={{0., 0.}, {-5.55112*10^-17, -2.77556*10^-17}}
```

I would be very thankful if some of you guys would try and help me understand why there is a difference between these two approaches, maybe what they have to do with MachinePrecision and perhaps what value is more accurate.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe as a further question: Are these types of error also to be expected in other languages, such as python?

Comment: Running your code a few times gives the impression that the difference is "floating point noise", that the order of operations differs between your version with the `Transpose` and the version without and this results in a difference at the edge of the precision you are using.  Adding the option `WorkingPrecision->64` or even `WorkingPrecision->1024` to your `RandomReal` shows that the difference between the two versions of the code is right at the edge of the precision of the floating point values that you are using.